# Identifying local highs in a chart

Tags: algorithm, quantitative-finance, candlestick-chart

## S&P 500 highs

Here's a chart of the S&P 500 going back before the year 2000.

[image]

People commonly refer to "all time highs" or "local highs" when talking about historical price data. So for example, the highs that folks might refer to are annotated above with the blue arrows.

## Program to find highs automatically

Instead of manually annotating a chart, I'd like to have a program which identifies the highs.

Here's a C# function which appears to work:

```cs
List<Candle> identify_highs(List<Candle> rows, TimeSpan threshold)
{
    var ls = new List<Candle>();

    var candidate = rows.First();
                    
    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        if (row.High > candidate.High)
        {
            var duration = (row.DateTime - candidate.DateTime).Duration();

            if ((row.DateTime - candidate.DateTime).Duration() > threshold)
            {
                ls.Add(candidate);

                candidate = row;
            }
            else
            {
                candidate = row;
            }
        }
    }

    ls.Add(candidate);

    return ls;
}
```

Here's a rough description of the algorithm:

```
Given a list of candles, let the first one be the `candidate`.

For each candle
    If the next candle is higher than the candidate
        If the next candle is far away from the candidate
            The candidate is a high.
            The candle is a new candidate
        Else
            The candle is a new candidate
```

If I run a program which plots the data and highs using this function with a `threshold` of `175` days, it outputs the following:

[image]

It also displays the highs on the console:

[image]

## Question

The `identify_highs` function used above is just a quick ad-hoc function put together for this program.

Is there a popular or established algorithm for identifying chart highs?

## Project

The entire program which generates the plot above is here:

https://github.com/dharmatech/IdentifyHighsCs/blob/master/IdentifyHighsCs/Program.cs

Comment: If your posted code already works, what objective, concrete improvement do you want to make? How can you measure that improvement?

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy to figure out. The last high (gray), and future low (orange)

[image: fig1]

**Figure 1.** Reverse time SP500 chart (oldest to the right)

Scan the data from oldest to newest and keep track of the maximum value (gray line above). For any period, the value of the gray line indicates the previous high.

Now scan the data from newest to oldest and keep track the minimum value (orange line above). For any period, the value of the orange line indicates the next low.

To find the dates where the last high and future low occurred, just find the date in the data that matches the values calculated.